SSIS Build failing with No Visual Studio instance with SSIS run time available in this machine
I have created a new SSIS project and the build is failing for following error in Azure Devops.
No Visual Studio instance with SSIS run time available in this machine
I created a new SSIS solution/project with one SSIS package. We use Azure dev-ops for build and deployment. When I build it locally, its completing without any issue. But when I trigger the build in Azure devops, its failing. The project is set to Deployment target version "SQL Server 2016". Is there any thing in the project/SSIS package that I need to check?
Other existing similar projects are building fine in the same machine. The only error message I get is following "No Visual Studio instance with SSIS run time available in this machine".
I am using Visual studio 2019.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent? Can you share more details about the Pipeline definition?
